# How to change the glowing color of a Button

Tags: wpf, button, focus

How to change the glowing color of a Button, I have edited the Control template of Button still i cant find the where does this glowing animation is done.

Could anyone guide me on this?

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonFocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ButtonNormalBackground" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#F3F3F3" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#EBEBEB" Offset="0.5"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#DDDDDD" Offset="0.5"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#CDCDCD" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonNormalBorder" Color="#FF707070"/>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ButtonFocusVisual}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBackground}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBorder}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ButtonChrome x:Name="Chrome" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}" RenderDefaulted="{TemplateBinding IsDefaulted}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ButtonChrome>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="RenderDefaulted" TargetName="Chrome" Value="true"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="RenderPressed" TargetName="Chrome" Value="true"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ADADAD"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: If you wrote your custom `ControlTemplate` then there should not be any animation unless you put it there. Can you share your XAML?

Comment: @dkozl: updated the code.. pls have a look..

Comment: Your `Button` is *not* glowing. Please explain what you mean.

Comment: @Sheridan: It will glow when it is focused. (Not sure in Win8 or later)

Answer (score 0):

First, lets understand what we're dealing with here... the default `ControlTemplate` for the `Button` control can be found at the [Button Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN. Unfortunately, it's far too big to copy here.

If you look at the `ControlTemplate` from the linked page, you will see a [`VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualstatemanager.visualstategroups%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) section. Inside this `VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups` section, you can see some [`VisualState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) objects... here is one of them:

```
<VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
    <Storyboard>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
            (GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
            Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" 
                Value="{StaticResource ControlMouseOverColor}" />
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

From the linked page:

> Each `VisualStateGroup` contains a collection of `VisualState` objects. A `VisualState` contains a collection of `Storyboard` objects that specify how the control's appearance changes when the control is in a certain state. For example, a `Button` might have a slightly different appearance when it is pressed than when it is not pressed. Two states that the Button defines correspond to when it is pressed ("Pressed") and when it is not ("Normal").

This is where the animations come from. We can prove this by declaring a really basic `ControlTemplate` for the `Button`:

```
<Button Content="Click me" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5" 
                Padding="5">
                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Note how there are no `Color` animations on this `Button`.

Answer (score -1):

If you are referring to the thin line (blue by default, in windows 7) around the button, that line is caused by the default theme.  You can test this by temporarily changing your windows theme and looking at the button again.

the easiest way to remove that behavior that I've found is to set the buttons style to the style of the toolbar button

```
<Button BorderThickness="0" Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" >
```

Comment: This disables the default button style as it looks like flat text.. My requirement is to disable the glowing button color when it is focused.